# Why is there only a small difference between Falcon 9 and Falcon Heavy launch prices?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, cost, falcon-heavy

SpaceX's website says that a Falcon 9 launch costs 61 million while a Falcon Heavy launch 85 million. Considering that the Falcon Heavy is almost three times bigger than the Falcon 9, I don't understand why is the difference in price so tiny.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [Why is there so little price difference between the Falcon 9 and the Falcon Heavy?](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5874/why-is-there-so-little-price-difference-between-the-falcon-9-and-the-falcon-heav). Please don't delete tho, slightly different wording might help others find answers easier. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. And sorry for duplicating, it was unintentional :(